# How to open another app from my android React Native app?

Tags: android, react-native

I want to open several other applications from my React Native app.
 Linking (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html) works great for apps like facebook, google maps, tel, skype **when I know their intent urls**, but what I want to run is default ebook reader, youtube, IPLA and a bunch of games preinstalled on tablet, which **urls / package names I don't know**.

My team ex-member year ago creates other app with cordova and he uses this tool: https://github.com/lampaa/com.lampa.startapp.

**Questions**: 
- whether there is some tool like lampaa startapp above, but for React Native, where I can run app with a package name, not url?
- how can I check the intent url (like 'fb:' for facebook, 'geo:' for g.maps) and package names (like 'com.google.android.apps.maps') of installed apps?
- how to run installed games and ebook reader, when I already have their package name but not url?

Android only, don't care about iOS.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @vinayr according to my knowledge the only way to do this without writing own java component is to make a  react native - cordova bridge with this tool: [link](https://github.com/axemclion/react-native-cordova-plugin) and just use cordova plugins. Unfortunatelly this is not working for me, app builds well but crashes immidiately after start. Good luck and please reply there if You succeed: [link](https://github.com/axemclion/react-native-cordova-plugin/issues/36).

Answer (score 0):

I don't whether it is possible to get `deep-link scheme` (like `fb:`, `geo:`) of other installed apps.

But you can get `Launcher activity` of other installed apps.

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

List<ResolveInfo> appList = pm.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
    Collections.sort(appList, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm));

for (ResolveInfo rInfo : appList) {
    Log.d("Launcher", "package:" + rInfo.activityInfo.packageName +
                      "; activity: " + rInfo.activityInfo.name);
}
```

Or you can directly launch another app:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(pacakgeNameOfTheApp);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Ok, but this looks like a native Java code, not JavaScript, and I don't know what to do with this :/ Do I need to know java to make apps in react native?